# change string to an object

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I can transform a string into an object.

Here is the string:

```
"{components: [\n  {\n    type: 'textfield',\n    label: 'FirstName',\n
   key: 'firstName',\n    input: true\n  },\n  {\n    type: 'textfield',\n 
  label: 'LastName',\n    key: 'lastName',\n    input: true\n  },\n 
  {\n    type: 'email',\n    label: 'Email',\n    key: 'email',\n 
  input: true\n  },\n  {\n    type: 'button',\n    action: 'Submit',\n  
  label: 'Submit',\n    theme: 'primary'\n  }\n]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an Angular question but more of a JS question. Anyways you can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), like this:

```js
const string = "{components: [\n  {\n    type: 'textfield',\n    label: 'FirstName',\n    key: 'firstName',\n    input: true\n  },\n  {\n    type: 'textfield',\n    label: 'LastName',\n    key: 'lastName',\n    input: true\n  },\n  {\n    type: 'email',\n    label: 'Email',\n    key: 'email',\n    input: true\n  },\n  {\n    type: 'button',\n    action: 'Submit',\n    label: 'Submit',\n    theme: 'primary'\n  }\n]}";
const obj = JSON.parse(string);
```

Explanation from the MDN docs:

> The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string

Comment: i tried that but it is saying ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (user-add.component.ts:72)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33)
    at FilterSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)

Comment: run code snippet on your answer too it is showing an error

Comment: That means your string is not formatted properly. It needs to be formatted properly before running it.

Comment: ok how can i store this as a string in my database {"components":[{"type":"textfield","label":"FirstName","key":"firstName","input":true},{"type":"textfield","label":"LastName","key":"lastName","input":true},{"type":"email","label":"Email","key":"email","input":true},{"type":"button","action":"submit","label":"Submit","theme":"primary"}]}

Comment: With JSON.stringify: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

This way you can parse it back with JSON.parse.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON standard requires double quotes and will not accept single quotes, nor will the parser.

So you can eval the string that will gives you result you wanted.

```js
// i never recommend this solution.
let component = eval(string) // Array(4)
```

A better solution is to use [JSON5 Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json5)

```js
const json5 = require("json5")
let obj = json5.parse(string) //{component: Array(4)}
```